# cannot resolve method getsystemservice in Fragment Class

Tags: java, android

how Can I use getSystemService in fragment class like the below code

```
final EditText input = new EditText(getContext());
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)  getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(input, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
// Specify the type of input expected; this, for example, sets the input as a password, and will mask the text
input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
//Show Automatic KeyBoard
input.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager) getBaseContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        keyboard.showSoftInput(input, 0);
    }
}, 50);
builder.setView(input);
```

Comment: try with getActivity().getSystemService

Comment: thanks alot Pravin it works well now

Comment: @DevDev don't forget to give reward to correct answer or helpful comment by up-vote. Advice to take tour of Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use 
`getActivity().getSystemService`